# What is this alif like sign?

Tags: quran, quran-recitation, uloom-al-quran

Assalamualaikum Shayekh.

In this ayah for example - 
عَلَىٰ سُرُرٍ مَّوْضُونَةٍ - 56:15

What is the alif like sign above ya of A'la? It seems to me like a verticle fathah but it's not pronounced in any recitation.

JazakAllah for your response (in advanced)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called `Al-Alif Al-Qaseera` (الألف القصيرة) that goes on top of `Al-Alif Al-Maqsoora` (الألف المقصورة) — which is drawn looking like a `ya'` (ى) — to show that the pronunciation of the `ya'` is like that of `alif`.

Traditionally, علىٰ (to mean "on") used to be written as علا (to mean "exalt" as in [Qur'an 28:4](https://quran.com/28/4/)):

[image: Example 1]

This caused confusion in distinguishing the meaning of the words, so it was replaced by `Al-Alif Al-Maqsoora` (على). But then, this introduced a problem of how to distinguish the pronunciation.

To distinguish the pronunciation, dots were used on top of or below letters to denote the different ligatures, as shown in the document below from a mushaf from North Africa. This way of writing ligatures has been partially re-adopted for ya' (ي) in the modern times, with two dots under it to replace `kasra` (the only tradition I am aware of that continue till today from this way of writing).

[image: Example 2]

Later on, `Al-Alif Al-Qaseera` was adopted to distinguish the pronunciation.

Note this `Al-Alif Al-Qaseera` does not get added when the following letter is `sakin` as in this verse for `موسى`:

[image: Example 3]

whereas, if the letter following is not `sakin`, then `موسى` will adopt `Al-Alif Al-Qaseera` on top:

[image: Example 4]

As you may have noticed, that `Al-Alif Al-Qaseera` is also used to replace (`badal`) the actual `alif` in a lot of words, typically for beautification of scripture, and is only used this way in scribing the Qur'an (which has different rules in scribing).

In addition, it may be used to differentiate different types of recitation as in the following example, which can be recited as `malik` or `maalik`:

[image]

For further information on this topic, you may refer to books on the topic (e.g., [رسم المصحف دراسة لغوية تاريخية](https://books.google.com/books?id=hz9ICwAAQBAJ)).

Comment: MaShaaAllah! What a detailed and in-depth answer! May reward you for all your effort and give barakah in your study on Quran!

Answer (score 2):

It is a sign that indicates a specific recitation in at least another valid qiraa'a. It can also refer to a possible *mad* مد (a prologation in the recitation) or just shows that the "yaa' ي" is recited as an"alif". It is not part of the Quran nor a valid sign of the rasm al 'Othmany of the moshaf. It is an addition to help the reader to read/recite the Quran as it was revealed.

I hope to find time to improve this answer.